# how to compare values of check box in if condtion?

Tags: php, forms, validation

i wanted to verify whether the options a,d are checked in check box it aint working when im taking multiple options it working fine with single option here is my html

```
<input type="checkbox" id="a" name="a" value="a" />aaa
<input type="checkbox" id="a" name="a" value="b" />bbb
<input type="checkbox" id="a" name="a" value="c" />ccc
<input type="checkbox" id="a" name="a" value="d" />ddd
```

here is my php if condition

```
if (($n == 1) && ($ans != ($_POST['a'] == 'a' && 'd' )))  
    {
        $result = "Wrong";
    }
```

some one plz help me....

Comment: Hint: _What does `print_r($POST['a']);` show?_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using a single name for 4 inputs, you should change `a` to `a[]` because you're working with arrays:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="a" name="a[]" value="a" />aaa
<input type="checkbox" id="a" name="a[]" value="b" />bbb
<input type="checkbox" id="a" name="a[]" value="c" />ccc
<input type="checkbox" id="a" name="a[]" value="d" />ddd
```

and then in your php code:

```
$arr = array('a', 'd');
if(count(array_intersect($arr, $_POST['a'])) == count($arr)) // if 'a' and 'd' are in the $_POST['a'] array
{
 // do some stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

simply use `if(in_array(a,b,c))`

Comment: can u plz explain me more clearly Im a beginner in php..plz